# Should we merge the 'Resources' and 'Resource-recommendations' tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

We currently have two tags, one with 60 questions, and the other with just 7.

[resources](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources) (60)

[resource-recommendations](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-recommendations) (7)

Should we make **resources** a synonym of **resource-recommendations**, or even leave just the second one, as we've done with other tags (*software-recommendations* and *hardware-recommendations*)?

I can't think of a resource question that is not actually looking for recommendations, but I might be missing something.

What do you think?

Comment: Software and hardware recommendations are very different, whereas these two tags are practically identically. I vote to merge them.

Answer (score 3):

I say merge them :) ... an additional 19 characters.